# Google Maps - Auto connect Places

Tags: google-maps

I have a personalized map within Google Maps with a bunch of places marked in the city of Tokyo.

Is it possible to *"auto connect"* / draw a walking path between those places without manually linking each place point?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the [Directions Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions), use this syntax when providing your `waypoints`:

```
{
  origin: "Chicago, IL",
  destination: "Los Angeles, CA",
  waypoints: [
    {
      location:"Joplin, MO",
      stopover:false
    },{
      location:"Oklahoma City, OK",
      stopover:true
    }],
  provideRouteAlternatives: false,
  travelMode: TravelMode.WALKIN,
  unitSystem: UnitSystem.IMPERIAL
}
```